# Best method to convert a CATEGORY to PROPERTY in emacs org file

Tags: elisp, org-mode

What is the best method to convert CATEGORY to PROPERTY in a org file.

```
#+CATEGORY: NETWORKING
```

to

```
:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY: NETWORKING
:END:
```

I have used the following elisp code to do this.

```
(let ((buf_name "home.org") (current_line 0) (current_string ""))
  (set-buffer buf_name)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "#\\+CATEGORY: \\(.*$\\)" nil t)
    (replace-match ":PROPERTIES:\n:CATEGORY: \\1\n:END:")))
```

Is there a better method.

EDIT:- the regular expression

```
"#\\+CATEGORY: \\(\\w+\\)"
```

has been modified to

```
"#\\+CATEGORY: \\(.*$\\)"
```

since i had a "C++" CATEGORY which is not recognized as a word, only the "C" in "C++" is recognized as a word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
(let ((buf_name "home.org")
      (current_line 0)
      (current_string ""))
  (with-current-buffer buf_name
    (replace-regexp "#\\+CATEGORY: \\(\\w+\\)"
                    ":PROPERTIES:\n:CATEGORY: \\1\n:END:" 
                    t
                    (point-min)
                    (point-max))))
```

But it's only a stylistic change, there is no conceptually better way.

Furthermore: property drawers and category are not equivalent: The second expand until the end of the file, the first only inside the current subtree.
So you most probably have to edit it manually afterwards.

Comment: Talespin_Kit's usage of `re-search-forward` and `replace-match` is more correct when writing lisp. The documentation for `replace-regexp` actually tells you to do exactly that, because it "will run faster and will not set the mark or print anything".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(save-excursion
  (let* (file-cat 
     (file-list (org-agenda-files t)))
    (dolist (file file-list)
      (find-file file)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (re-search-forward "CATEGORY")
      (setq file-cat (substring-no-properties 
              (org-get-category (point))))
      (beginning-of-line)
      (kill-line)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (outline-next-heading)
      (org-set-property "CATEGORY" file-cat)
      (while (not (condition-case nil (outline-forward-same-level 1)
            (error t)))
    (org-set-property "CATEGORY" file-cat))
      (save-buffer))))
```

The above code gets the file category, removes the deprecated line, and then sets the CATEGORY property of each top level headline to the old file category.

Edit: Edited the code to accommodate the case pointed out by Jonathan

Comment: How will this work if your #+Category is the line after your top level headline so that it propagates through all subheadlines? (* Top \n#+Category: Category\n** blah\n** blah2)

Comment: I have edited the code to accommodate that case. Thanks for pointing it out.